# отображение нужных элементов списка

Tags: angularjs, angular2

Есть список проектов, у каждого из проектов есть свойство is_active при включенном чекбоксе нужно выводить только активные проекты(is_active = 1), а если снять выделение то все проекты.
вот код вывода обьектов

```
<input type="checkbox" checked>
<tr ng-repeat-start="project in displayedCollection" name="project-
{{::project.project_id}}">

Some data of project
<tr>
```

Я думал сделать как-нибудь через ng-if но не могу придумать как туда впихнуть 2 условия что бы все работало?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="filter.key">
<tr ng-repeat-start="project in displayedCollection | filter:{'is_active': filter.key ? 1 : undefined} track by project.project_id">
    ...
<tr>
```